# Jenkins plugin to parse/modify commit messages

Tags: jenkins

When I open "Project - Changes" pages in Jenkins I see following output:

```
1. Bug 12345 fix
2. Bug 12346 comment #12 fix
3. Bug 12347 development
4. ... and so on
```

I'd like the string like `Bug 12345` or `Bug 12346 comment #12` be links to corresponding bug tracker's page (Bugzilla in our case).

Is there a ready-to-use plugin doing this work?

Or how easy would it be to modify existing plugin (and which one)? Or write some script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Bugzilla+Plugin

According to description it supports Issue Highlighting
[image: issue highlightting]